# /Page works but /page is a 404? What gives nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am confused about an issue related to the case of the links I am using.

For example:

https://example.com/page (does not work)

but

https://example.com/Page (does work)

Why do only the capitalized pages work when navigating my next site? I only want lowercase links to work.

Example of page code:

```
import React from 'react'

// Custom layout
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import '../sass/styles.scss'

import SupportSection from '../components/SupportSection'

function Support() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container-fluid border-bottom">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row spaces">
            <div className="col-md-3 sidebar">
              <h1>Support</h1>
              <div className="med-spaces">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-9 mt-3">
              <SupportSection />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Support
```

Comment: may be because u have page inside `Page/index.js` by default it calls `index` page.

Comment: @xdeepakv I double checked all cases for files/folders. its in /pages and all files and folders are currently lowercase

Comment: What is your production filesystem when building this? I am sure during dev you don't face this issue, correct?